# Finding the occurrence of a property in a javascript Object and adding it's count as another property using es6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Looking for help to transform the data present in the below format using es6. I have tried using reduce but that simply gives me the count as a value to each property. However, I need to have that value to be added as another count property in an object.

Have provided the desired output below.

```
data = [  {
category_desc: "Analytics Solution",
category_id: "analytics solution",
},
{
category_desc: "Analytics Solution",
category_id: "analytics solution",
},
{
category_desc: "Data",
category_id: "data",
},
{
category_desc: "Education",
category_id: "education",
},
{
category_desc: "Instruction",
category_id: "instruction",
},
{
category_desc: "Journey",
category_id: "journey",
},
{
category_desc: "Journey",
category_id: "journey",
},
{
category_desc: "Support",
category_id: "support",
},
{
category_desc: "Support",
category_id: "support",
},
{
category_desc: "Support",
category_id: "support",
},
{
category_desc: "Support",
category_id: "support",
}
]
```

And I am looking for data to be transformed into the below format using es6

```
[{
id: "analytics solution"
desc: "Analytics Solution"
count: "2"
type: "Category"
},
{
id: "data"
desc: "Data"
count: "1"
type: "Category"
},
{
id: "education"
desc: "Education"
count: "1"
type: "Category"
},
{
id: "instruction"
desc: "Instruction"
count: "1"
type: "Category"
},
{
id: "journey"
desc: "Journey"
count: "2"
type: "Category"
},
{
id: "support"
desc: "Support"
count: "4"
type: "Category"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using a simple [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const data = [{
    category_desc: "Analytics Solution",
    category_id: "analytics solution",
  },
  {
    category_desc: "Analytics Solution",
    category_id: "analytics solution",
  },
  {
    category_desc: "Data",
    category_id: "data",
  },
  {
    category_desc: "Education",
    category_id: "education",
  },
  {
    category_desc: "Instruction",
    category_id: "instruction",
  },
  {
    category_desc: "Journey",
    category_id: "journey",
  },
  {
    category_desc: "Journey",
    category_id: "journey",
  },
  {
    category_desc: "Support",
    category_id: "support",
  },
  {
    category_desc: "Support",
    category_id: "support",
  },
  {
    category_desc: "Support",
    category_id: "support",
  },
];

const [desc, id] = ['category_desc', 'category_id'];

const counts = data.map((obj) => {
  return { ...obj,
    count: 1
  }
})

counts.forEach((obj, index) => {
  const double = counts.find(({
    [desc]: d,
    [id]: i
  }, ind) => d === obj[desc] && i === obj[id] && ind !== index);
  if (!double) return;
  double.count++;
  counts.splice(index, 1);
});

console.log(counts)
```